# Explicitly inheriting from 'type' to implement metaclass in python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, metaclass

I was trying to get some intuition about metaclass in Python. I have tried on both Python2.7 and   and Python3.5. In Python3.5 I found every class we define is of type `<class 'type'>` whether we explicitly inherit or not. But if not inherited from **type** we can't use that class as a metaclass for another class.

```
>>> class foo:
    pass

>>> class Metafoo(type):
    pass

>>> foo
<class '__main__.foo'>
>>> Metafoo
<class '__main__.Metafoo'>
>>> type(foo)
<class 'type'>
>>> type(Metafoo)
<class 'type'>
>>> 
>>> class foocls1(metaclass=foo):
    pass
```

doing the above I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#52>", line 1, in <module>
    class foocls1(metaclass=foo):
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

But that is not in the case while using Metafoo as metaclass for the new class

```
>>> class foocls3(metaclass=Metafoo):
    pass

>>> foocls3
<class '__main__.foocls3'>
>>> type(foocls3)
<class '__main__.Metafoo'>
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case that we need to explicitly inherit if we want to use a class as metaclass in other class.

Comment: Every class is an *instance* of `type`, but they're not all *subclasses* of `type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"type" is the base class for all class objects in Python 3, and in Python 2 post version 2.2.  (It is just that on Python 2, you are supposed to inherit from object. Classes that do not explicitly inherit from "object" in Python 2 were called "old style classes", and kept for backward compatibility purposes, but were of little use.)

So, what happens is that inheritance: what are the superclasses of a class, and "metaclass" that is "since in Python a class is an object itself, what is the class of that object" are two different things. The classes you inherit from define the order of attribute (and method) lookup on the instances of your class, and therefore you have a common behavior.

The metaclass is rather "the class your class is built with", and although it can serve other purposes, is most used to modify the construction step of your classes itself. Search around and you will see metaclasses mostly implementing the `__new__` and `__init__` methods. (Although it is ok to have other methods there, but yu have to know what you are doing)

It happens that to build a class some actions are needed that are not required to build normal objects. These actions are performed on the native-code layer (C in CPython) and are not even reproducible in pure Python code, like populating the class's special method slots- the pointers to the functions that implement the `__add__`, `__eq__` and such methods. The only class that does that in CPython is "type". So any code you want to use to build a class, i.e. as a metaclass, will have to at some point call `type.__new__` method.  (Just as any thing you want to create a new object in Python will at some point call the code in  `object.__new__`.).

**Your error happened** not because Python goes checking whether you made a direct or indirect call to `type.__new__` ahead of time. The error: "TypeError: object() takes no parameters" is simply due to the fact that `__new__` method of the metaclass is passed 3 parameters (name, bases, namespace), while the same method in `object` is passed no parameters. (Both get te extra "cls", equivalent to self as well, but this is not counted).

You can use any callable as the metaclass, even an ordinary function. It is just that it will have to take the 3 explicit parameters. Whatever this callable returns is used as the class from that point on, but if at some point you don't call `type.__new__` (even indirectly), you don't have a valid class to return.

For example, one could create a simple method just in order to be able to use class bodies as dictionary declarations:

```
def dictclass(name, bases, namespace):
    return namespace

class mydict(metaclass=dictclass):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3

mydict["a"]
```

So, one interesting fact with all that is that `type` is its own metaclass. (that is hardcoded in the Python implementation). But `type` itself also *inherits* from object:

```
In [21]: type.__class__
Out[21]: type

In [22]: type.__mro__
Out[22]: (type, object)
```

And just to end this: it is *possible* to create classes without calling `type.__new__` and objects without calling `object.__new__`, but not ordinarily from pure Python code, as data structures at the C-API level have to be filled for both actions. One could either do a native-code implementation of functions to do it, or hack it with ctypes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation